# How to calculate the median of a list of numbers from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, median

I was working on doing a short function on finding a median from a list.
Here is a portion of the csv file:

```
Index,Height(Inches),Weight(Pounds)
1,65.78331,112.9925
2,71.51521,136.4873
3,69.39874,153.0269
4,68.2166,142.3354
5,67.78781,144.2971
6,68.69784,123.3024
7,69.80204,141.4947
8,70.01472,136.4623
9,67.90265,112.3723
10,66.78236,120.6672
11,66.48769,127.4516
12,67.62333,114.143
13,68.30248,125.6107
14,67.11656,122.4618
15,68.27967,116.0866
16,71.0916,139.9975
17,66.461,129.5023
18,68.64927,142.9733
19,71.23033,137.9025
20,67.13118,124.0449
21,67.83379,141.2807
22,68.87881,143.5392
23,63.48115,97.90191
24,68.42187,129.5027
25,67.62804,141.8501
26,67.20864,129.7244
27,70.84235,142.4235
```

Can someone help me in this?
I have tried to use `Counter` also to count the number of items.
I want to find the median of the third column.
My preexisting function is:

```
def median():
   n = (len(file_data))
   file_data.sort()
   if n%2==0:
    median1 = file_data[n//2]
    median2 = file_data[n//2-1]
    median = (median1+median2)/2
    mediankg1 = median/2.2046
   else:
      median = file_data[n//2]
      mediankg = median/2.2046
   print("MEDIAN")
   print("Median is " + str(median)+" pounds")
   print("OR")
   print("Median is " + str(mediankg1)+" kilograms")


median()
```

Comment: What about using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to read your CSV file then call [`median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas for this, as it has built in functions for these tasks. The install documentation is found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

The following code should be enough to get you started:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', header=None)

median_col = df.median(axis=0) # Median of each column
median_row = df.median(axis=1) # Median of each row

median_row_3 = median_row[2] # Median of 3rd column
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you don't want to use pandas:

```
import csv
file_data = [float(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(open(csvfile), delimiter=',')]

n = len(file_data)
file_data.sort()
median = file_data[n//2]
if n%2==0:
    median = (median+file_data[n//2-1])/2
mediankg1 = median/2.2046
print("MEDIAN")
print("Median is " + str(median)+" pounds")
print("OR")
print("Median is " + str(mediankg1)+" kilograms")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.